# how to use auto convert of type detect in typescript when I use '=='

Tags: typescript

when I use '==' to judge equality between string and number,

```
const a = '1234';
const b = 1234;
// This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'number' have no overlap.
const c = a == b;
```

typescript show an error: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'number' have no overlap.

but we kown the code works in javascript;

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA5ARgEwGYAsKDcAUKJLAEZIya5EnQzCUKLJlFA)

so is there any way to remove the error except using Number function to convert?

Comment: The particular wording of the error message is bad (longstanding open issue at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26592 about it), but the error itself is a good one.  The problem with the comparison has little to do with whether the condition will "always return `false`" (which isn't even true) but with the fact that you should not be comparing two unrelated types like that.  TypeScript takes the position that such comparisons are probably developer errors; if you really want to do it, write `(+a) == b` or even better `(+a)===b`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [equality operator (`==`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) to compare two values which are known to be `string` and `number` by the compiler will always result in this error. You can either use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) on one of the values, or use an abstraction to do the comparison (like the function in the example below):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwE4FMCiBHEyA2iAFMgFyLgDWYcA7mADSIBG5VN9AlOc3HPumRIA3gChEiDFBCokyRAF4FLANyiAvqNEQEAZygpFiAOQBGAEwBmACzG1OsPpZGLNtQIMQefAULXajeSVVRAB6ACpxCUQAPzj40QAVAAsYXUQHABMYWAREWhh8QgJaZABPdKkZJGNgAl10Y0RdGEh0RChk9qgygAd0dON9VFaAcyahTJMwEABbZnRUJuTkADd2mkQ4ddR8ZF6AOiIrADYAdk5EcNCtCECMHDx8EiZmThUw0K3KAOVDZHS7DoSGCzA+oS+cB+QA)

```ts
function areEqual (a: unknown, b: unknown): boolean {
  return a == b;
}

const a = '1234';
const b = 1234;
let c: boolean;

c = a == b; /*
    ~~~~~~
This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'number' have no overlap.(2367) */

c = areEqual(a, b); // ok
c =  a as unknown == b; // ok
```

---

However, if the compiler doesn't know for sure that the values are `string` and `number`, you won't have a problem with the direct comparison:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/DYUwLgBAhhC8EHICMAmAzAFgdAzhHYATgJYB2A5hAD4SkCuAtgEYiEDcAUKJE3BKplz4iZSjXrNWnDgGMA9qQIQZfGLHhM2EAPTaIcgNZA)

```ts
let a = '1234' as string | number;
let b = 1234 as string | number;

const c = a == b; // ok
```